# Creating new indexin in list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

In Python, if I want to add one element like below, what do I need to do (without using build-in-function)?

```py
a = [0,1,2,3]
a[3+1]=4
print(a)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cyber/Program/Python/Design Thinking/Python code/q2.py", line 18, in <module>
    a[3+1]=4
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: You can't. You have to _append_ to a list if you want to add more elements to it. You cannot access an index of a list if it doesn't already exist, even if that access is to set a value to it.

Comment: You _could_ get what you want by making `a` a dictionary, but then you'd have to manually specify the keys for the initial elements like `a = {0: 0, 1: 1, ...}`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to add the value 4 to the end of list *a* in which case:

```
a = [0,1,2,3]

a += [4]

print(a)
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

However, if you want to add a value at, say, index 5 then you can't do that without extending the list to accommodate that index and any missing ones. What are known in other languages as sparse lists (arrays) don't exist in Python. Of course you could write something yourself

Comment: if i want to add in for loop like
a = [1,2,3,4]
for i in range(0,10):
 for j in range(0,5):
  a[i+j]=int(input())

Comment: Why not just `a.append(4)`?

Comment: @fsimonjetz The OP doesn't want to use built-in functions

Comment: @CyberKarthik That's a different question altogether. Please raise a new question for that